# XAML reference to System.Windows.Controls.BooleanToVisibilityConverter

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-core-3.1

In my WPF-application, targeting .NET Core 3.1, I'm trying to use the built-in [System.Windows.Controls.BoolToVisibilityConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter?view=netframework-4.8)

I think I have looked up the correct syntax for the XAML reference.

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
```

However I get a compile error:

```
'System.Windows.Controls' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference. Also, verify that your project and all referenced assemblies have been built.
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter?view=netcore-3.1

It's not in the dll you're using.

Namespace:
System.Windows.Controls

Assembly:
**PresentationFramework**.dll

Change the assembly.

```
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=PresentationFramework"
    >
<Window.Resources>
    <controls:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolConv"/>
</Window.Resources>
```